# sharepoint breadcrum trail editing on the fly

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have been searching for hours now and have found some code that claims to be able to do what i want however...it doesn't.

I am currently trying to remove Pages and .aspx off the end of my page name in the breadcrumb trail in sharepoint. Currently it look like....
mysite > myarea > pages >mypage.aspx

I have tried changing the SiteMapProvider and this takes away the pages link as well as the current page. It then looked like..
mysite > myarea.

I would like to have 
mysite > myarea >mypage
I have tried using this snippet of code...I do not claim to own or to have developed this code.

```
var breadCrumbs = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb_ContentMap')
if (breadCrumbs != null) {
    if (breadCrumbs.childNodes.length >= 3) {
        if (breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML.indexOf('Pages') > 0) {
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "";
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I put some document.writes in to see where the code was getting to and the breadCrums variable seems to be null therefore the code never gets to the juicy part :P

Any ideas hints tips would be hugely appreciated

Truez

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on a SharePoint site and was able to get the breadCrumbs element just fine.  Have you verified that that is the correct ID of your breadcrumbs object.  The ID you use is the default, but you should check.  Just view source on the page and do a quick <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and search for "*Breadcrumb*".

Too see if it is just a matter of placement, do this: On a target SharePoint page using IE, open the Web Developer tool (**Tools** > **Developer Tools**).  Switch to the **Script** tab and press the <kbd>Multi Line Mode</kbd> button at the bottom of the script pane.  Paste this code:

```
var breadCrumbs = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb_ContentMap')
if (breadCrumbs != null) {
    if (breadCrumbs.childNodes.length >= 3) {
        if (breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML.indexOf('Pages') > 0) {
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "";
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            alert('Pages node NOT found!');
        }
    } else {
        alert('breadCrumbs only has ' + breadCrumbs.childNodes.length + ' children!');
    }
} else {
    alert('breadCrumbs NOT found!');
}
```

Then press the <kbd>Run Script</kbd> button.  This code is just yours with some alerts added to help you see if/where it fails.  If you get no alerts and the breadcrumbs element changes as you expect then yes it is placement.  Otherwise, it depends on which alert you get.  Let me know the results and I can help you correct the issue.

Comment: I have checked using the IE web developer tool!...So many times aswell!...... I have put this script above the <head> tags i believe...Is this where it should be... i was just thinking maybe the control doesn't exist when the script is called...Could this be the issue?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give some troubleshooting tips, let me know what you find.